# Вывести в конечный файл числа разного знака,использовать для перемещения fseek

Tags: c++

Дан файл с положительными и отрицательными числами.Вывести в конечный файл числа так,чтобы они были разного знака,то есть,если число(n+1) имеет один и тот же знак,что и предыдущее(n), то (n+1) нужно удалить.

Comment: @tatasue, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @tatasue, а что делать с "непарными" числами? 

Например:

    -2 3 -4 -5 -6 -7 8


-5, -6 и -7 -- выводить в конце или выбросить?

Тут ведь дело в том, что если строго следовать тексту задания, то fseek() вообще не нужен.